# How to LEFT JOIN with multiple cases

Tags: sql, join

Assuming I have these two tables like:

Table: tab1

| valA | valB | valC | valD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | A |
| 2 | 11 | 333 | A |
| 3 | 44 | 444 | B |
| 3 | 66 | 666 | D |

Table: tab2

| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | A |
| 1 | 22 | 222 | A |
| 2 | 44 | 333 | B |
| 3 | 55 | 555 | A |
| 3 | 66 | 666 | D |

I have 3 cases that I have unite with UNION. This is the code:

```sql
WITH tog AS
(

SELECT* FROM tab1
INNER JOIN tab2
ON ValA = Val1
AND ValB = Val2 

UNION

SELECT* FROM tab1
INNER JOIN tab2
ON ValA = Val1
AND ValB <> Val2  
AND ValD = Val4

UNION

SELECT* FROM tab1
INNER JOIN tab2
ON ValA = Val1
AND ValC = Val3
AND ValD <> Val4
)
```

The result would be:

table: tog

| valA | valB | valC | valD | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | A | 1 | 11 | 111 | A |
| 1 | 11 | 111 | A | 1 | 22 | 222 | A |
| 2 | 33 | 333 | a | 2 | 44 | 444 | B |
| 3 | 66 | 666 | D | 3 | 66 | 666 | D |

So, I need the table of tab1 but **without** the matches, like:

| valA | valB | valC | valD | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 44 | 444 | B |  |  |  |  |

I tried something like this, but I know this is totaly wrong:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tog
ON tab1.valA = tog.val1
WHERE tog.val1 IS NULL
```

I am pretty new on SQL so I would appreciate any tipps and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select data from tab1 where not exists a match in tab2.

```
select *
from tab1
where not exists
(
  select null
  from tab2
  where tab1.vala = tab2.val1
  and 
  ( 
    (tab1.valb = tab2.val2) or
    (tab1.vald = tab2.val4 and tab1.valb <> tab2.val2) or
    (tab1.valc = tab2.val3 and tab1.vald <> tab2.val4)
  )
);
```

Or, if you need the empty tab2 columns:

```
select *
from tab1
left outer join tab2
  on tab1.vala = tab2.val1
  and 
  ( 
    (tab1.valb = tab2.val2) or
    (tab1.vald = tab2.val4 and tab1.valb <> tab2.val2) or
    (tab1.valc = tab2.val3 and tab1.vald <> tab2.val4)
  )
)
where tab2.val1 is null; -- dismiss the matches
```